# General questions about Restcomm SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, restcomm

I am starting an application using Restroom and have a few questions about the iOS SDK.

I read through the documentation here http://documentation.telestax.com/restcomm-ios-sdk/doc/html/Classes/RCDevice.html#//api/name/listen

I have also checked out this:
https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-ios-sdk

1. I see that the RCDevice class has a listen method and an unlisten method.  If I want the device to always be available to receive calls should I have the listen method always going? If so, is this going to be terrible for battery life?
2. How do I make sure that the application is always running on the device so that it can always receive calls?  I am pretty sure that iOS 10 will stop background connections unless the app is running in the foreground.
3. Is there a way to wake the application or open the application in the case of an incoming call?  Can I use push notifications or something similar to wake/open the app?

Answer (score 0):

I already replied to this question on the Restcomm Forum, but let me also answer here for better visibility by the community:

1. Yes, once you call unlisten() you will no longer be registered and hence receive no incoming events.
2. Ok, so it varies per platform. For Android since the SDK is wrapped in an Android Service even when the App leaves the foreground, the SDK continues running and you are able to receive events (we still need to check some updates on Android O though on that respect). For iOS we haven't implemented that yet so once you leave the foreground you are not able to receive any events :(. However, the plan is to move to Push Notifications functionality on both platforms soon.
3. Please check (2). Also, without Push Notifications, we were planning of supporting this with https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-ios-sdk/issues/153, but also this isn't ready yet.

Best regards,
Antonis Tsakiridis